# Is there any way to automatically recieve api data (if any change in it) in React JS apart from component did mount and other available methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react js app and tried other available methods to fetch data from an API. I am looking for ways so that if there is an update in the API, react js automatically reflect an updated data. I have already tried component did mount and setting an interval, but looking for other ways.

Comment: You should use socket at BE and FE both for this case. So in case if there is any change in data at BE, then BE will emit a socket event. The FE will have to listen to this event.

Comment: If you have control over the server code, use sockets. Otherwise you probably have to keep checking at regular intervals like setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Well for triggering side effects you can use the ComponentDidMount life cycle method if you are working with class components, or the useEffect hook if you are using functional components. Those are for when you need to trigger effects such as API calls when a component is rendered.

You can also trigger those effect using events based on client actions when interacting with your app, like press a button, a scroll event, a form submit, etc.

However the thing you are actually asking about reflect a change in the UI based on some API update is the use case for websockets. Check this link for getting a basic understanding of the use of websockets with React https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/
Also when you are ready check the official repository of SocketIO https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-socket-io